# Ubuntu 16.04 Terminal/ Server problems and more

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates, software-center, update-manager

I've been having this really frustrating problem with Ubuntu lately. I am not at all an experienced Linux user.

I've been trying to use Ubuntu Terminal to install some packages and applications but nothing has been working so far. Nothing at all and it's really frustrating!

I for example try to use "sudo apt-get update". It keeps getting stuck at 0%.
I try changing the server in Software and Updates but then it says  "Querying software sources" and after that a window appears saying "Failed to download repository information", "Check your Internet connection".
When I click on the "details" tab on that last window, I get this long message that I do not understand:

```
W:The repository 'cdrom://Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20170801) xenial Release' does not have a Release file.,
Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
W:See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details. 
W:Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/InRelease  Could not connect to 47.88.32.46:3128 (47.88.32.46), connection timed out
W:Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/InRelease  Unable to connect to 47.88.32.46:3128:
W:Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-backports/InRelease  Unable to connect to 47.88.32.46:3128:
W:Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-security/InRelease  Unable to connect to 47.88.32.46:3128:
W:Failed to fetch https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/dists/xenial/InRelease  Connection timed out after 120001 milliseconds 
W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu/dists/xenial/InRelease  Could not connect to 47.88.32.46:3128 (47.88.32.46), connection timed out  
E:Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20170801)/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  

Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. 
apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs, 

W:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead."
```

Every time I try to install a package it fails because it is unable to locate it. It's like my whole Ubuntu system can't connect to any server at all and can't exchange any data with it.

Please help me! 
Thank you.

Comment: 47.88.32.46 is a server in the `alibaba.com` domain. Moreover, `apt` isn't supposed to retrieve packages by IP address, only by the fully qualified URL. Your `/etc/hosts` file may be compromised. What is the output of `ping archive.ubuntu.com`?

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply and thank you very much for your answer. The output it gives is: "64 bytes from danava.canonical.com (91.189.88.149): icmp_seq=40 ttl=43 time=210 ms"

Comment: Notice that this is now a different IP address. This one is definitely in the canonical.com domain. Perhaps you sould just try again. If the 47.88.32.46 address pops up again there is something wrong with your setup.

Comment: Hi when I try again I get the same IP address. What exactly should I change in my setup? I was thinking of just reinstalling Ubuntu but I didn't want to have to reinstall all my programs.

Comment: See in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/` if a proxy server has been configured, and if yes, if it points to that IP address 47.88.32.46 and port 3128. If so, remove it.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I managed to fix the problem. I went to the /etc/apt/apt.conf file and deleted all the proxy attributes. After that it still didn't work at first but then I check my proxy settings in Networks. I noticed that even tho proxy was set to "none", it was actually configured. So I set it to manual and deleted the proxy present. Thank you again!